# Image processing : How to can i use this code like getpixel and setpixel

Tags: c#, image-processing, .net-core

Hello guys i saw this code in microsoft docs and i need to use it like getpixel and setpixel , clean code examples thanks .

```
private void LockUnlockBitsExample(PaintEventArgs e){

    // Create a new bitmap.
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

    // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bmp.PixelFormat);

    // Get the address of the first line.
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
    int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

    // Copy the RGB values into the array.
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

    // Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
    for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
        rgbValues[counter] = 255;

    // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

    // Unlock the bits.
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    // Draw the modified image.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150);

}
```

I need i way to use this code like getpixel and setpixel functions with good explanation and clean code thanks .

Comment: Look at Wiki for definition of a bmp format.  I was looking at it a few weeks ago while answering another posting and it gave good example of setting colors.

Comment: See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358865/c-sharp-faster-way-of-setting-pixel-colours).  It explains how the how to locate and access individual pixels.

Comment: Are you on .NET Core or WinForms or both?